The uniqueness of a solution Impossible chessboard puzzle
This is a double post.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4981887/the-uniqueness-of-a-solution-impossible-chessboard-puzzle/4981946#4981946
I found a video about a famous puzzle called  "Almost imopossible chessboard puzzle"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=as7Gkm7Y7h4
and a website that shows us a lot of solutions of it.
https://www.cantorsparadise.com/a-fascinating-prisoners-puzzle-be874032f43e
Now I'm wondering if all the solutions are essentially equivalent.
If they are, could you give me a proof?
To be precise, let me describe the problem.
Let $n$ be a power of  2 and $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,\cdots n\}$ is a function such that for any $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ and $a\in \{0,\cdots, n\}$, there exists $x'\in \{0,1\}^n$ s.t $x$ and $x'$ have same component except one component and $f(x')=a$
My question is if $g:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,\cdots n\}$  has the same property, then are there bijections $\phi:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ and $\psi:\{0,\cdots n\}\rightarrow \{0,\cdots n\}$ s.t $f=\psi\circ g\circ\phi$?
Here $\phi$ should have the property that if $x$ and $x'$ have same components except one,
$\phi(x)$ and $\phi(x')$ have same components except one.

I see neither chessboard nor prisoner in the description you give.
